# Local storage solutions for large data including images on React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, realm, offline

Here's the flow of how my end-product should work:

1. When the user opens the app for the first time, fetch all the data
   i.e., including images(150+) and relevant JSON objects.
2. On opening the app subsequently, the images and data should load
   from local storage i.e., no need for internet at all.

I know it seems weird but this is my use case:

The product is a Wayfinder running on Android Box(55-inch touchscreen TV ) which will be placed in the shopping mall. It will not have access to the internet unless I manually connect it.

Hence it should load the data when opening for the first time i.e. when I'm configuring the application.

Solutions I have come across:

**Realm**: Local database management with excellent support for react-native - **my option right now**

**Native Async Storage**: Not suitable for large data

**SQLite**: Not comfortable with SQL queries

I'm still looking for options on how differently this problem can be tackled. Also, I'm familiar with **Redux**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) (or [expo-file-system](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-file-system) if working with expo).

It is specially designed to store files on the device. In your component, it would look something like this:

```js
const RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

RNFS
    .downloadFile({ fromUrl: myURL, toFile: myFilePath })
    .promise
    .then(res => console.log('Done'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use pouchDB database , this is work with indexDB local browser database

call XHR request for image and convert response to binary data and store in local database

when need to preview image , get from database and make a blobUrl and show in `img` tag

```
    axios.get(url, {
                    progress: false, responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                    onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                        precent = (100 * progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)
                        console.log(precent)
                    }
                })
.then(resp => {

                    //get db
                    let db = $db.dbModel

                    //set attach
                    db.get(doc._id).then((doc) => {

                        db.putAttachment(doc._id, 'index.mp4', doc._rev, new Blob([new Uint8Array(resp.data)], {type: 'video/mp4'}), 'video/mp4')
                            .then(res => {
                                // console.log('success store file')
                            })
                    })

                })
```

https://github.com/mohammadnazari110/pwa_offline_video_download